# Failed to instantiate module, KARMA

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I've finished to implement my web site with AngularJS and now, I must make my unit test to verify the correct functioning of my functions.

I was looking for a lot of tutorial on internet but apparently, my application structure doesn't allow testing with karma and jasmin.

Let me explain, I got a site web with just one single page HTML which is linked with one controller (a file .js) I've never installed Angular with NPM but I've imported it with:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And I load my controller with:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

and some other imported script.

I would like to try my controller with unit tests, so I've created a package.json file and installed karma, jasmine, and karma-cli with npm.

I've make a folder called "Tests" and created a test.js file:

```
describe("App",() =>{ //Describe object type
  beforeEach(module('App')); //Load module
  describe('Ctrl',()=>{
    var Ctrl;
    beforeEach(inject( ($injector)=>{   //instantiate controller using $controller service
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(($controller)=>{
      Ctrl = $controller("Ctrl");
    }));

    it("Should say hello",()=>{
      expect(Ctrl.msg).toBe("Hello");
    })
  })
})
```

But when I use:

> karma start

it's doesn't detect my controller.

Here is my console output:

[image: output]

Here is my karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jun 14 2018 16:51:15 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [ 'Scripts/angular.js','Scripts/angular-mocks.js','main.js','Tests/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

And how i declare my controller :

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope','$http','$timeout','$mdDialog','Global', 'projects', 'screens', 'users', 'licenses', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout, $mdDialog,Global, projects, screens, users, licenses) { 
...
}
```

Here is my tree folder :

```
-Root
  |---node_modules
  |---Tests
  |     |---test.js
  |---Scripts
  |---index.html
  |---main.js   <--- controller of my index.html
  |---style.css
  |---someFactory.js
```

I don't think I'm doing it in the right way. Please, explain me how to do it.

Comment: You probably need main.js in this enumeration in karma.conf.js: `files: [ 'Tests/*.js' , '*.html', 'main.js'],`

Comment: Ok, i just added `files: [ 'Tests/*.js' , '*.html','*.js']`  it's look like it don't search anymore in the \base folder. but i always have that error on the loading of my controller : `module is not defined`